# Карты Yandex загружаются только после перехода по странице

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, angular

Использую Yandex Maps API и Angular 6. Когда я запускаю Angular CLI сервер то в консоль всегда выбивает:

> MapsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
>
> ERROR ReferenceError:
>   ymaps is not defined
>       at MapsComponent.push../src/app/main-layout/main-layout/maps.component.ts.MapsComponent.ngOnInit
>   (maps.component.ts:19)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9243)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11062)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MapsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10451)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:10692)

Но после того, как я прохожу по роутингу например на `/login` компонент и возвращаюсь обратно, то карта вдруг появляется.

Мой index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=...&lang=ru_RU"type="text/javascript"></script>
...
</html>
```

В maps.component.html есть:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
```

maps.component.ts содержит:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MainLayoutService} from '../main-layout.service';

declare var ymaps:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html'
})

export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
  properties: object;
  public map :any;

  constructor(private service: MainLayoutService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    ymaps.ready().then(() => {
      this.map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [50.450100, 30.523400],
        zoom: 6
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: а если переместить скрипт яндекс карт в `head`? хотя как-то у вас непонятно, у вас элемент `script` после бади?

Comment: @overthesanity
Имя я поменял потом, для анонимности. Это не имеет значения

Comment: @overthesanity Ну да, я все скрипты помещал после бади. Честно говоря уже не помню почему, где-то утверждалось, что это бест практис, или для лэзи загрузки. Не помню. Поместил, короче в хэд, карта появилась, но в консоль кинуло вот что:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'map' of undefined

Comment: не знаю где вы вычитали про этот бест практис :)) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037769/10123947 можно полную ошибку?

Comment: @overthesanity Вот:

zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'map' of undefined
    at push../src/app/main-layout/main-layout/main-layout.component.ts.MainLayoutComponent.initMap (main-layout.component.ts:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)

Comment: покажите метод `initMap`

Comment: @overthesanity
  initMap() {
  this.map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [50.450100, 30.523400],
    zoom: 6
  });

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87164/discussion-between-overthesanity-and-kiryl-aleksandrovich).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите скрипт загрузки карт в `head`, чтобы он полностью прогрузился до работы с DOM. Также ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'map' of undefined` возникает из-за потери контекста, вам нужно либо биндить его:

```
ymaps.ready().then(this.initMap.bind(this));
```

Либо использовать стрелочную функцию:

```
private initMap = () => {
    ...
}
```